# Image uploading using CKEditor in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, ckeditor, wysiwyg, image-uploading

I am using CKEditor in my application as rich text box. It is used to provide bullets and numbering.
Now we need to upload images in between the text. So how can i accomplish this? What all configuraion is to be set? Also should i use CKFinder for this? If so please detail me on this.

Comment: Everything is very clearly explained on the CKEditor site. http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: I am not clear about it. Am using asp.net mvc to build my appln. I have already given  filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/UploadImage', filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: "/UploadImage". But am confused with the path i have given. when browse for the image i get the error:
Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. Requested URL: /UploadImage

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

In view.

```
filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '../../Upload/uploadnow'
```

In Controller

```
public ActionResult uploadnow(HttpPostedFileWrapper upload, string CKEditorFuncNum)
    {
        string path = "";
        string pathWeb ="";
        if (upload != null)
        {
            string ImageName = upload.FileName;
            string extention = Path.GetExtension(ImageName);
            string name = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyMMddhhmmssms");
            ImageName = name + extention;
            pathWeb = "/images/uploads/" + ImageName;
            path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/images/uploads"), ImageName);
            upload.SaveAs(path);
            HttpContext.Response.Write("<script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + pathWeb + "\");</script>");
            HttpContext.Response.End();
        }
        return View();
    }
```